# CakePHP 2.9.7 Model::beforeSave()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x, cakephp-2.9

Is it possible to know what kind(INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) of query is going to be executed beforeSave() because there is user which can update only and other that can insert only and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To distinguish between an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` you can check if the model's `id` has been defined:-

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (! empty($this->id)) {
        // UPDATE
    } else {
        // INSERT
    }

    return parent::beforeSave($options);
}
```

If content is being deleted then `beforeDelete()` is called instead of `beforeSave()`.

```
public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
    // DELETE

    return parent::beforeDelete($cascade);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @drmonkeyninja.
I completely forgot about beforeDelete()